# Find min and max in variable number of values in array

Tags: python, pandas, max, min

I have a dataframe with multiple arrays in a column.
I am trying to find the min and max of each column.

I can split an array with a single value and find the min and max from there (`[9.75 x 8.00]`) but it becomes more complicated when there are multiple values in an array (`[10 x 14, 10 x 11, 1.5 x 1.75]`).

Here is what I have:

```
df[['Length', 'Width']]=df['Array'].str.split("x",expand=True,)
df['Max'] = df[['Length', 'Width']].values.max(1)
```

Here Is what I am trying to get:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Array": ["[9.75 x 8.00]", "[10 x 14, 10 x 11, 1.5 x 1.75]", "[54 x 80, 39 x 75, 78 x 80, 39 x 80, 54 x 75, 60 x 80]"],"Max":["[9.75]", "[14,11,1.75]", "[80,75,80,80,75,80]"],"Min":["[8.00]", "[10,10,1.5]", "[54,39,78,39,54,60]"]})
```

Comment: Please add your code as [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficult part is to strip and split your strings:

```
df1 = df['Array'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ').explode().str.split(' x ', expand=True)

df[['Max', 'Min']] = pd.concat([df1.max(1).groupby(level=0).apply(list), 
                                df1.min(1).groupby(level=0).apply(list)], axis=1)
```

Output:

| Array | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [9.75 x 8.00] | [9.75] | [8.0] |
| [10 x 14, 10 x 11, 1.5 x 1.75] | [14.0, 11.0, 1.75] | [10.0, 10.0, 1.5] |
| [54 x 80, 39 x 75, 78 x 80, 39 x 80, 54 x 75, 60 x 80] | [80.0, 75.0, 80.0, 80.0, 75.0, 80.0] | [54.0, 39.0, 78.0, 39.0, 54.0, 60.0] |

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the terrific answer

Comment: lol. Do you need some explanation? :)

Comment: I have been working on this for a while but this answers my question. I didnt even think about splitting them and then using the groupby function but that makes sense